# Why does a segmentation fault appear with this data structure?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

Given the datastructure

```
#define DATASTRUCTURE_H

#define MAXINDEX 307

typedef enum {So, Mo, Di, Mi, Do, Fr, Sa} eDayofTheWeek;

typedef struct{
    int Day;
    int Month;
    int Year;
    eDayofTheWeek WeekDay;
} sDate;

typedef struct{
    int Hour;
    int Minute;
    int Second;
}sTime;

typedef struct sALE{
    sDate Date;
    sTime Time;
    char *Description;
    char *Location;
    sTime Lenght;
    struct sALE *Next;
    struct sALE *Prev;
    int ID;
}sAppointment;

typedef struct sLE{
    sAppointment *Appointment;
    struct sLE *Next;
}sListEntry;

typedef struct{
    sListEntry *first;
    sListEntry *last;
}sHashEntry;

extern sHashEntry AppIndex[MAXINDEX];
extern sAppointment *First, *Last;

#endif
```

which will be used to create a appointment with sListElement in this function

```
sListEntry *Create = malloc(sizeof(sListEntry));
    if(Create != NULL){
        enter(1);
        printf("Termin erstellen");
        enter(2);
        if(getDate("Datum: ", &(Create->Appointment->Date))){
            if(getTime("Uhrzeit[Std:Min]: ", &(Create->Appointment->Time))){
                if(getDuration("Dauer[Std:Min:Sek]: ", &(Create->Appointment->Lenght))){
                    if(getText("Terminbeschreibung: ", 100, &(Create->Appointment->Description), 0)){
                        if(getText("Ort: ", 15, &(Create->Appointment->Location), 1))
                            check = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The segmentation fault happens when `getDuration` appears after I type an input:

```
int getDuration(char *prompt, sTime *time){
    char in[20];
    int Len;

    do{
        printf(prompt);
        scanf("%[^\n]", in);
        clearBuffer();
        Len = strlen(in);
    }while(!(getTimeFromStringLite(in, time)) && (Len != 0));

    return 1;
}
```

(`getDuration` asks the user for an input in hrs:min:sec format and adds it to the data structure, also allowing the user to make no input in there)

Why is that happening?

It worked back then when I did the same code but with the datatype `sAppointment` which is now included in `sListEntry` but since I changed the datatype and adapted the variables a segmentation fault appears. The variables are the only thing changed. Every other function stayed the same.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide a [mcve] (one piece of code that can be copied, pasted and compiled without guesswork and without the need to stitch pieces of code together). Also provide minimal input that leads to the crash. Maybe the problem is in the parts of the code you didn't show, who knows.

Comment: doesn't look like youre allocating space for `Create->Appointment`, so as soon as you `Create->Appointment->` you dereference an uninitialized pointer, invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: @yano well spotted in this mess... That is indeed a problem, maybe there is more....

Comment: This kind of behaviour indicates undefined behaviour in your code. UB does not have to result in any particular behaviour like segfault

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the comment: "doesn't look like youre allocating space for Create->Appointment, so as soon as you Create->Appointment-> you dereference an uninitialized pointer, invoking undefined behavior."

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Please ```delete``` your answer and make it below the statement you have already quoted.